# Why useEffect may return a ClearInterval() on a SetInterval effect?

Tags: reactjs

In the following code from reactjs.org:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      // Read latest props at any time
      console.log(latestProps.current);
    }

    const id = setInterval(tick, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []); // This effect never re-runs
```

as my brain compiles it, the effect created is a "wait one second then do something", but the setInterval being async itself, it returns immediately then useEffect return its closure callback. React being aware of states changes only and not of actions (it doesn't know what was launched in the useEffect, isn't it? How could he know!), I suppose that it'd fire the closure callback directly on return and then prevent the tick() function to be fired even ounce... but it's not the case. How comes ? How React knows what to wait before firing the closure callback returned by useEffect?

Comment: Are you asking how react knows when to run the function returned from the callback function of the `useEffect` hook?

Comment: To find the answer to those kinds of questions please consult the [documentation for useEffect (with cleanup callback)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup). I don't think stackoverflow should be the first resource to turn to.

Comment: You were right Martin: I read that page yesterday, and I clearly missread/didn't read that sentence: "React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts". Thank you very much, and sorry for that unnecessary question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know exactly what happens in the background, for implementation sake you need only to know that the return callback of a useEffect is only called when the effect is re-ran, or more specifically, after "closing" the previous effect-run and before the new effect running. Depending on the effect's dependencies, it can be on every render, or (as in the example you posted) only when the component is unmounted.

It's useful to think that functional components are just functions, so unless the function (the component) is called again (a re-render or other lifecycle change), the effect is "stopped", there's no magical parallel process. I would risk saying that react checks the hooked effects on a component in pre and post render. Depending on dependencies and the effect's details, it knows whether it should call the return callback or not call the effect at all.

See [this sandbox I created](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-chebyshev-e3y6i?file=/src/App.js) where I demo these two most extreme cases: effect on every render, and effect only on mount/unmount. Check the sandbox console to understand the behavior. Try to change the parent's effect dependencies to `[count]` and see the differences.

PS: when I started using hooks, this article helped me a lot https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: Thank you very much for the very useful sandbox/explanation and your link @pavlag! I'll clearly have a deep look at it as soon as I finish reading the reactjs.org doc :)